# Are C programs compiled with MSVC JIT or AOT?

Tags: c, visual-c++

An acquaintance of mine claims that any program compiled with the MSVC compiler is JIT compiled, as it is using the Visual C runtime, and that compilation with the GCC toolchain on Windows makes a fully AOT compiled output. Is this true?

Comment: Native C and C++ EXE, DLL  are compiled to assembly.  Perhaps they are confusing native win32 with .NET?

Comment: C programs compiled with MSVC are not JITted. They are compiled to assembly and then linked to make an executable file. Your *comp sci student* is wrong.

Comment: I knew this, they were just very insistent that they were correct as they are a programmer and I am not. I was seeking clarification. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Note that MS does -- or at least did at one time -- support compiling C and C++ to CLR bytecode that runs on a .NET VM.  Presumably, such programs are subject to JIT just as C# programs are.  But that has never been the default for MSVC, and I'm uncertain whether it requires a separate tool.  You can find several Q&A here about it.  Microsoft uses its own tools internally, and they produce a lot of software that runs natively. Not least, Windows and the .Net VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite very similar names C,C++ and C# are not the same languages.

C & C++ are compiled languages and the compiler generatrates the machine level code.

C# is generally compiled and interpreted (or better said JIT compiled)  language at the same time. C# code is compiled to the special IL format which JIT compiled to the machine code. As it is JIT compiled you may dynamically runtime create assemblies - so the code may modify itself runtime. (Reflection emit)

So I believe that you have asked about the `C#`.

Comment: This person was very insistent that they were referring to plain C and C++. As others have also said they were wrong, I can safely say that my initial thoughts were correct. Thanks for clarifying.